# Why (*func)() is the same as (*************************func)()?

Tags: c, function-pointers

code like this works:

```
int func()
{
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int (*f)() = func;
    int x = (*************************f)();  //x = 1

    return 0;
}
```

Why?